# Reverse for 'note' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found error in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

My URL:

```
url(r'^(?P<task_id>\d+)/note/$', login_required(NoteView.as_view()), name='note'),
```

After note is successfully saved, I want to redirect to the note url with the task_id thus I am using `reverse` function:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website.views.note', args=(task_id,)))
```

My URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/1/note/
```

I think the reverse works only `http://localhost:8000/note/1/` but not on `http://localhost:8000/1/note/`. How can I make it work?

Comment: Why you want to do it in `/1/note` than `/note/1` ?

Comment: Whole URL pattern in the application is `/1/note`. Just trying to make it uniform, that's all.

Comment: Try using a list instead of a tuple when sending the arguments.

Comment: Yes done, still not working :(

Comment: @user2032220 Can you show the `/note/1` url definition?

Comment: What do you mean by URL definition

Comment: Yes the exact same code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given the URL a specific name - `'note'`. That means you can't reverse it as `'website.views.note'`, but only as `'note'`.

```
reverse('note', kwargs={'task_id':task_id})
```

Comment: Still the same error `Reverse for 'note' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'task_id': u'1'}' not found.`

Comment: The problem was I was using `namespace` thus `reverse('website:note', kwargs={'task_id':task_id})` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the keyword args as

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website.views.note', kwargs={'task_id':task_id,}))
```

Comment: @user2032220, is that your exact code or you missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Write :

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('note', kwargs={'task_id':task_id,}))
```

**URL Name Should be unique**. Here, "note" should be unique. Just pass "note" in HttpResponseRedirect.